# Highstock Make Blank for yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock Chart looks like [IMG1], I want it's yAxis can has a Blank space like [IMG2], and please note that the blank in [IMG2] keeps the lines.

I tried to set the charts margin/spacing/offset and not working. do you know how to set the blank?

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

Comment: The offset parameter works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/0e69quwc/, can you verify and if is still wrong, update my code with yours?

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks! but it's still wrong, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/L5hxhdy2/1/   I want to make a blank area on the right, and the numbers on the right should keeps the lines. the lines is missing in your code. take a look of [IMG2]

Comment: You can set the negative tickLength parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/f231wcLn/